# Проблема с загрузкой точек на Яндекс-карту в режиме RemoteObjectManager при z > 11

Tags: яндекс-карты

При масштабе больше чем 11, точки перестают отображаться на Яндекс-карте.
Но при этом, если двинуть карту вверх, а потом обратно вниз, то все необходимые точки появляются.
Монитор 1920x1080, масштаб 150%, - то есть формально это уже 1280x720.

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/control/medorganizations

[image: Новороссийск при масштабе z = 11]

[[image: Новороссийск при масштабе z = 12 - нет ни одной точки][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJGxg.jpg)

[image: Новороссийск при масштабе z = 12 - посл того как двинул карту наверх, а потом вниз]

Тестовый гео-объект, находящийся в Мысхако (координаты 44.658134,37.76115) :

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/control/medorganizations/1083497

[Новороссийск, поселок Мысхако, аптека Ригла](https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/control/medorganizations/1083497)

Все тайлы, к которым относится точка с координатами 44.658134,37.76115
( формула взята отсюда https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames )

| x        | y        | z  |

|        0 |        0 |  0 |

|        1 |        0 |  1 |

|        2 |        1 |  2 |

|        4 |        2 |  3 |

|        9 |        5 |  4 |

|       19 |       11 |  5 |

|       38 |       23 |  6 |

|       77 |       46 |  7 |

|      154 |       92 |  8 |

|      309 |      184 |  9 |

|      619 |      369 | 10 |

|     1238 |      739 | 11 |

|     2477 |     1478 | 12 |

|     4955 |     2957 | 13 |

|     9910 |     5915 | 14 |

|    19821 |    11831 | 15 |

|    39642 |    23662 | 16 |

|    79284 |    47325 | 17 |

|   158568 |    94650 | 18 |

|   317137 |   189301 | 19 |

|   634275 |   378603 | 20 |

|  1268550 |   757206 | 21 |

|  2537101 |  1514412 | 22 |

|  5074202 |  3028824 | 23 |

| 10148405 |  6057648 | 24 |

| 20296810 | 12115297 | 25 |

Все запросы к тайлам, которые идут от Яндекс-карты при z=12, если в центре находится Мысхако (юг Новороссийска):

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2475&y=1480&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2475_y_1480_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2475&y=1481&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2475_y_1481_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2475&y=1482&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2475_y_1482_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2475&y=1483&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2475_y_1483_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2476&y=1480&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2476_y_1480_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2476&y=1481&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2476_y_1481_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2476&y=1482&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2476_y_1482_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2476&y=1483&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2476_y_1483_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2477&y=1480&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2477_y_1480_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2477&y=1481&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2477_y_1481_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2477&y=1482&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2477_y_1482_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2477&y=1483&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2477_y_1483_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2478&y=1480&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2478_y_1480_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2478&y=1481&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2478_y_1481_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2478&y=1482&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2478_y_1482_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2478&y=1483&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2478_y_1483_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2479&y=1480&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2479_y_1480_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2479&y=1481&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2479_y_1481_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2479&y=1482&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2479_y_1482_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2479&y=1483&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2479_y_1483_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2480&y=1480&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2480_y_1480_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2480&y=1481&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2480_y_1481_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2480&y=1482&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2480_y_1482_z_12

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2480&y=1483&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2480_y_1483_z_12

Диапазон по x правильный - от 2475 до 2480.

А вот диапазон по y не правильный - от 1480 до 1483.
На самом деле это просто море к югу от Новороссийска.

Поэтому наш тестовый гео-объект из тайла (x=2477, y=1478, z=12) и не отображается на карте.
Просто он не попадает ни в один из тайлов, которые опрашивает Яндекс-карта при увеличении масштаба до z = 12.

Правильный диапазон по y должен был быть от 1477 до 1480.

Со стороны сайта все работает нормально, и запрос по тайлу (x=2477, y=1478, z=12) выдает адекватный список гео-объектов Новороссийска:

https://roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/controlajax/medorganizations?ajax_get_tile=1&x=2477&y=1478&z=12&callback=myCallback_x_2477_y_1478_z_12

Таким образом становится понятно, почему в Новороссийске появляются точки при перемещении карты на север и потом обратно.
В тот момент, когда пользователь свигает карту на север, происходит аяксовый опрос более южных тайлов, - в которых как раз и находится Новороссийск.
При передвижении же карты обратно на юг, у Яндекс-карты уже есть информация по тайлам Новороссийска, - и поэтому все нормально отображается.

Замечу, что точно такая же картина наблюдается и попытке просмотра любого региона России.
Например, Калининград:

[image: Калининград при масштабе z = 11]

[[image: Калининград при масштабе z = 12 - нет ни одной точки][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qsPg.jpg)

[image: Калининград при масштабе z = 12 - посл того как двинул карту наверх, а потом вниз]

Соответственно, вопрос. Как это починить?
Проблема в том, что все выглядит как ошибка работы API Яндекс-карт.

Comment: Это не лечится если использовать проекцию сферического меркатора https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/projection.sphericalMercator-docpage/ ?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Добавил строчку про sphericalMercator, и все заработало как надо:
myMap = new ymaps.Map('mymap', {
center: (center_coord1 || center_coord2) ? [center_coord1, center_coord2] : [65.436604, 94.613945],
zoom: parseInt(@{[$$DATA{map_zoom} || 3]}) + parseInt(level),
behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom']
}, {
searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
projection: ymaps.projection.sphericalMercator
});